# Three.js strange clipping issue at distance

Tags: javascript, firefox, three.js

I am getting a strange issue with some code in three.js

I have a galaxy being created, and everything looks fine, except randomly a weird shape will appear in the center of the galaxy, sometimes black, sometimes white and it is always a different shape with different points, I believe this is a clipping issue but I am unsure.

Any assistance is appreciated.

See Image Below for Example of clipping behavior.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to a simple live example (not your entire project)?

Comment: I have no way of pulling this one piece out of the project.

Comment: OK. Can you show a live version of what you have?

Comment: You can only access it from facebook. 

https://apps.facebook.com/mmofourxspace/